# wordpress theme not showing posts

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I'm just trying to apply a Wordpress theme to my website but it does not work as it should and I don't know why. Have tried to fix it but I ended up with nothing.

The theme is available on Github, it's [this one](https://github.com/hakkens/davehakkens) but when aplying it to [my site](http://www.juanperea.net/) the main page does not show any post although I have lots of them. They have told me that the theme uses a javascript to load the posts but i don't know if that's the reason why the posts are not showing or not because I think I'm doing all as I should and not missing anything. [This](https://davehakkens.nl/) is how it should look like.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: On your page, click F12 while in Chrome (inspect). If you have any errors you'll see a red circle notifying you of an error on your page. If your posts are loaded via javascript, maybe the file with the js code isn't loaded. Also in your wp-config.php enable debug. Also read [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @dingo_d. Have tried inspecting it with Chrome and also enabled debug mode on the theme but nothing is shown nor circled in red. It seems that everything it's okay but well... it is not. :/

Comment: You have 2 errors on your page:
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT http://www.juanperea.net/wp-content/plugins/google-analyticator/external-tracking.min.js?ver=6.4.9` and `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-54ac9b76616e81c6`

Comment: @dingo_d Oh, I didn't see them. Thank you for telling but I think those are not related with the posts if I'm not wrong, will continue trying to see if I can fix it.

Comment: They are js errors, and they could be preventing your js code from executing. Also check if all your js scripts are loaded.

Comment: You are right. Are they still showing up? I think I deleted the plugins causing them. Sorry for answering but how can I check that? @dingo_d

Comment: AS pgk suggested, your main.js file is missing. You can inspect your site by pressing F12 in Chrome (like pgk suggested). Check your functions.php file to see if there are dependancies that main.js has, and if any of them is missing, that's why it's not loaded.

Comment: It seems that that's the problem, for any reason the main.js is not been downloaded. In functions.php there is a dependancie; `wp_enqueue_script( 'dh_main', get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/js/main.js', array( 'jquery', 'fancybox', 'isotope', 'scroll_to', 'mousewheel', 'dh_plugins' ) );` but I think nothing is missing since it is the same file of the original theme.

Comment: I can't see fancybox javascript file and isotope loaded on your site. You can try to remove those dependencies (except for jquery) and see if it will work, or if you'll get an error...

Comment: @dingo_d That was really close. Deleting the fancybox dependencie makes the page try to load something but still get an error on jquery.js. `http://www.juanperea.net/wp-content/themes/davehakkens/loopHandler.php?numPosts=10&pageNumber=1&skipPosts= 404 (Not Found)` which could be related with fancybox? Or I don't know..

Comment: @dingo_d The `404 (Not Found) error` was just because of the theme folder name, solved it quickly but the main problem was that a plugin I had, called Easy Fancybox, was making the theme's javascript files not to work properly. Since you told me the fancybox thing I was able to make it work, if not I don't know if I could have find what was going on there. Thank you very much for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, happy I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your theme, in `wp-content/themes/davehakkens-master/` inside `js/` folder I can't find [`main.js`](https://github.com/hakkens/davehakkens/blob/master/js/main.js) file.

Original structure should be:

```
/js
   /vendor/
   - plugins.js
   - main.js
```

In your folder you have only `plugins.js` file but not the `main.js`

In this file there is `function init`, which should be the initial function of the plugin.

Look folder structure in the original theme or in `github`.

Comment: You mean [`this`](http://www.juanperea.net/wp-content/themes/davehakkens-master/js/main.js) file? I think I already have it on my server.

Comment: When I check your server `http://www.juanperea.net/` in Chrome Developer Tools I can't find this file been downloaded neither in Network panel or Sources panel. [screenshot1](http://1drv.ms/1OP0YJM), [screenshot1](http://1drv.ms/1OP11Fp). For this reason I decided that it's missing. To be shure, try to `console.log` something from there.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that the problem is what you said, the main.js is not been downloaded. Problem is I don't know why since I have not modified anything from the original theme available on github. How could I `console.log` or know why it is not been downloaded? I'm sorry but my coding skills are very limited. :/

Comment: Glad I could help. I don't know why this file is missing, but when you put it on the right place, should work. And I will be glad if you mark my answer as  right one :). About `console.log` - basically  in any place in your .js file you can put this command `console.log(var_to_show, 'some string');` and inspect variable value in the console. Check this article for start [console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui)

Comment: Thank you! I was able to make it work finally, the problem was that a plugin I had was making the theme's javascript files not to work properly. Don't know exactly why, maybe because they were using a very similar code or something but yup, that was the problem.